# Relate/link vendor bill to purchase order in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have created vendor bill with nlapiCreateRecord, I can see the Bill record in the system with all items I want, but I can't relate it / link it to specific Purchase Order natively. When I'm using nlapiTransformRecord I'm deleting all records first from the PO and I'm adding new line items from CSV, but the native link/relationship between PO and Vendor Bill is missing. Here is my code created for the Bill Import from CSV:

```
function BillImport() {

var fromrecord;
  var fromid;
  var torecord;
  var record;
  var qty;

  fromrecord = 'purchaseorder';
  fromid = 23664;
  torecord = 'vendorbill';

var loadedBillFile = nlapiLoadFile(5034);
var loadedBillString = loadedBillFile.getValue();
var BillLines = loadedBillString.split('\r\n'); //split on newlines

  record = nlapiTransformRecord(fromrecord, fromid, torecord);
  //trecord.setFieldValue('location', 1);
  //trecord.setFieldValue('tranid', 'TEST!');

  //var record = nlapiCreateRecord('vendorbill');

    for (var j = record.getLineItemCount('item'); j>=1; j--)
   {

       record.removeLineItem('item',j);

   }

    for (var i = 1; i < BillLines.length; i++) {
     var cols = BillLines[i].split(';');

     var dsplit = cols[4].split(".");
     var date = new Date(dsplit[2],dsplit[1],dsplit[0]);
     currentDate = date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();


  var entity = cols[0]; // OK HEAD
  var currency = cols[1]; // OK LINE
  var taxcode = cols[2]; // SKIP
  var tranid = cols[3]; // OK HEAD
  var trandate = currentDate; // OK HEAD FORMAT 11/3/2016
  var location = 21;//cols[5]; // OK HEAD (ID of Location)
  var item = cols[6]; // OK LINE
  var quantity = cols[7];
  var rate = parseFloat(cols[8]); // FLOAT
  var amount = parseFloat(cols[9]);
  var po = cols[10];


  record.selectNewLineItem('item');

  // Head Level
  record.setFieldValue('createdfromstatus','');
  record.setFieldValue('entity', entity);
  record.setFieldValue('tranid', tranid);
  record.setFieldValue('trandate', trandate);
  record.setFieldValue('location', location);

  // Line Level
  record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','item', item); 
  record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity', quantity); 
  record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','rate', rate);
  record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','amount', amount);
  //record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','orderdoc', po);
  //record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','podocnum', po);

  record.commitLineItem('item');   

  }

  var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);

  //trecord.setLineItemValue('item', 'amount', 1, 3 );
  //var idl = nlapiSubmitRecord(trecord, true);
}
```

Here is the example CSV file:

```
Entity;Currency;Taxcode;Tranid;TranDate;Location;Item;Quantity;Rate;Amount;PO Internal ID
2449;USD;0.00 ;224676;11.3.2016;21;885;1;10;50;23664
2449;USD;0.00 ;224676;11.3.2016;21;870;2;10;120;23664
2449;USD;0.00 ;224676;11.3.2016;21;890;3;3;45;23664
2449;USD;0.00 ;224676;11.3.2016;21;948;4;4,66;38,5;23664
2449;USD;0.00 ;224676;11.3.2016;21;886;5;19,54;720;23664
```

I'm

Comment: Why don't you use nlapiTransformRecord()?

Comment: Because, it automatically is importing all items of the purchase order. Can I transform it without the items?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to transform into a Vendor Bill (probably to avoid the PO from changing status) then you will need to create a custom relationship. You do this by:

1. Create a custom field on the Vendor Bill form of type "List/Record" and have the it be of "Transaction" type and check "Record is Parent". Save the Custom Field.
2. Go back to the custom field and edit it. Go to the display tab and select a "Parent Subtab", I usually select "Related Records". Save.
3. Now you just need to create a new Vendor Bill from scratch and save the record id of the PO in the Vendor Bill using the new custom field. Leave the "Created From" field blank, otherwise you would be linking them natively. The Bill should be listed under the "Related Records" tab or whichever subtab you selected on the PO.

Comment: I want to link a bill created with nlapiCreateRecord('vendorbill'); to record type 'purchaseorder' natively. The bill is created successfully, but not linked.
When I'm using nlapiTransformRecord to transfrom bill to purchaseorder I can insert new lines with selectNewLineItem from CSV in the newly transformed bill, but can't remove the lines that are coming from the purchase orders - the lines of the purchase order are in the bill.

Comment: You gotta use nlapiTransformRecord and you gotta leave at least 1 line from the PO if you want to link it natively, if you delete all lines then it is no longer is linked natively.

Comment: To delete some items from the transform record use something like: var transform = nlapiTransformRecord('purchaseorder', 12345, 'vendorbill'); transform.removeLineItem('expense',1) ; //For line 1

Comment: Thanks that's a great information. I didn't know I need to leave at least 1 line from the PO to link it natively.

Comment: What if I want to import fresh lines - I don't want to use the lines from PO, I have CSV file which I'm parsing in my script and don't want to use original lines from PO. I can't use my lines and link the Vendor Bill to PO. When I transform the PO to Vendor bill in my script I'm deleting all lines first and I'm adding the new one from CSV. That's loosing the native link/relationship between PO and Vendor Bill. I need a solution! What is the best way to transform PO to Vendor Bill and put a new line items from the CSV?

Comment: I was on the same situation and I ended up using the custom relationship I described above.

Comment: Thanks @Adolfo Garza I will try your solution very soon.

Comment: If I'm using your solution I will see them linked together - PO with the Bill?

Comment: Hello, I was able to link them without your method. I will post later the right answer.

Comment: Did you use orderdoc and orderline?

Comment: @scheppsr77 yes I just used orderdoc and orderline I created the function to find the line id of every line in the bill.

Comment: Have you ever seen a way to do this on an existing vendor bill? orderdoc and orderline work when first creating the bill. However, once it has been created, it doesn't appear to be possible to use orderdoc/orderline to add new lines and link them to PO lines.

Answer (score 0):

Vendor bill import via CSV method is doable but you can bill the Purchase Order completely and not partially i.e. if you try to import a bill mentioning any referenced Purchase Order's link in it, it'll create a bill for all the remaining unbilled quantities of the Purchase Order rather than the quantity you have mentioned.
Actually if you mention any quantity AND Purchase Order link BOTH in the CSV file then it will throw an error.
Below is the part I found from the SuiteAnswers with answer id as 10020.

[Refer the supporting image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L736P.png)